# Invoking Google Cloud Run service using Workflow Identity Federation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts, federated-identity

I'm trying to invoke a service which I have deployed to Google Cloud Run. It is a simple 'hello world' service but with 'require authentication' as the authentication option.

I am trying to call it from an AWS EC2 instance, using the workflow identity federation.
I have followed the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds
(and I also found [this](https://notificare.com/blog/2022/10/21/Accessing-Google-Cloud-From-AWS/) helpful) and I have proved that it is successfully impersonating the service account, as this following code running from the EC2 instance works to successfully list the GCP storage buckets:

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

async function main() {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
      });
      const client = await auth.getClient();
      const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
      console.log('projectId = ', projectId)
      // List all buckets in a project.
    const url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=${projectId}`;
    const res = await client.request({ url });
    console.log(res.data);
  }
  
  main().catch(console.error);
```

However, when I try to call my Cloud Run service using the following code:

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

async function main() {
  const targetAudience = 'https://my-cloud-run-service.a.run.app/'
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      targetAudience: targetAudience
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    console.log('projectId = ', projectId)
    
    // it's fine up to here
    const url = targetAudience;

    // this fails with HTTP error 401 unauthorised
    const response = await client.request({url});
    console.log(response);

  }
  
  main().catch(console.error);
```

then it fails with:

```
GaxiosError: 
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

    at Gaxios._request (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:141:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AwsClient.requestAsync (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js:246:24)
    at async main (/home/ubuntu/trader2/testAuth.js:15:22)
```

Now if I set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the service account key itself, rather than the file downloaded when I grant the service account access to the workflow identity federation, and call `getIdTokenClient` instead of `getClient`, then it works fine.
This is kind of acceptable, because as long as I protect the service account key file, then it's still secure enough. But I would just like to get the recommended way working if possible - frustrating that there must be one piece of the puzzle I'm missing!

Does anyone know a configuration step I may have missed, anything to test, or if there's anything wrong with my code?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Part 1: Your code is generating an OAuth Access Token. That works fine for calling Google services, but not user-managed services such as Cloud Run. You need an OIDC Identity Token (do not confuse it with GetCallerIdentity token) to call a Cloud Run endpoint and you must add the `Authorization: Bearer REPLACE_ME_WITH_IDENTITY_TOKEN` yourself when making HTTP requests.

Comment: Part 2: I don't know the Node.js libraries for Workload Identity Federation, but refer to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#external-idp) for details on how to generate an OIDC ID Token using Google STS.

Comment: When you use Workload Identity Federation, you get an access token from the STS server. This type of token is fine to call Google Cloud APIs. But not your OWN apis (Cloud Run/Cloud Functions). As shown  by John, you have to request an ID token to the IAM credential API. But... It's strange that the auth library does not manage that by default. Be sure to have the latest version of the library and don't hesitate to open an issue in the Github repository.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, thanks very much for your help. That does certainly help my understanding somewhat. Unfortunately the bit under 'Advanced Scenarios' in the link you posted about generating an ID token contains too much stuff I don't understand. For instance, the key value pairs under "A GetCallerIdentity token looks similar to the following" - where do I get the parameters to put in the values from?

I will update the question with some further code that I have tried in response to your comments

Answer (score 1):

Success - I've got it working using the below code.

Many thanks @JohnHanley - this info you provided me about using the access token to exchange for an OIDC access token, the difference between the authorization requirements between google services and invoking user-managed cloud run services, and the endpoint to use to gain the OIDC token, has just provided the missing piece of the puzzle. So thanks again, much appreciated.

However I do think like @guillaume-blaquiere says, it would be nice if this were part of the library.

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const axios = require('axios')

async function main() {
  const targetAudience = 'https://my-cloud-run-service-url.run.app/'
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      targetAudience: targetAudience
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const accessTokenResponse = await client.getAccessToken();
    const accessToken = accessTokenResponse?.token;
    if(!accessToken) {
      throw new Error("accessToken not present");
    }

    const serviceAccountEmail = client.getServiceAccountEmail()
    const getServiceTokenData = {
      audience: targetAudience
    }
    const getServiceTokenHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
    const getServiceTokenConfig = {
      headers: getServiceTokenHeaders
    }
    const getServiceTokenResponse = await axios.post(
      `https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/${serviceAccountEmail}:generateIdToken`,
      getServiceTokenData, getServiceTokenConfig
    ) // this is simply the call from https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#external-idp ,  written in JS

    const idToken = getServiceTokenResponse.data.token;
    const resp = await axios.get(targetAudience, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}`
      }
    })

    console.log(resp.data)

  }
  
  main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: My only hesitancy about using this in production is, how 'chatty' is the flow? How many network calls would this make compared to simply using a service account key? My preference for using libraries as opposed to roll your own solutions is that you are making the most of any caching opportunities that have been worked out - I'm not sure if there are any caching opportunities here that I'm missing.

Comment: Your code at first glance is fine for production. I often write similar code without using the libraries at all. Your code has three parts. a) normal Google SDK code to fetch an Access Token; b) request an OIDC Identity Token; c) make an HTTP request using the Identity Token. The default lifetime for both tokens is 3600 seconds. You can easily store them in an object to cache until expiration, then refresh them.

Comment: Weirdly I can now get it working on one EC2 instance but not the other.

I did initially grant access to a principal containing the EC2 instance ID, but have now completely deleted that WIF and recreated one just using a role, which they have both got. 
Any ideas what AWS config I might have to do in respect of that? It may be something I did on the other one, but can't remember.

Comment: OK John I will do, I've figured out what it is, so will answer the question and leave it there for posterity (if nothing else so when I forget next time, I'll be able to go back to it!)
Thanks again for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595982/one-aws-instance-can-call-google-cloud-run-service-using-wif-but-another-cant/77595983#77595983

Comment: Excellent. I entirely missed the `AwsClient` part of the stack trace. That indicates an AWS issue instead of a GCP issue.