# One AWS instance can call Google Cloud Run service using WIF, but another can't

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-run

Related to/following on from this question: [Invoking Google Cloud Run service using Workflow Identity Federation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77592354/invoking-google-cloud-run-service-using-workflow-identity-federation/77594859?noredirect=1#comment136796323_77594859)

I'm finding one instance can successfully call the Google Cloud Run service using Workflow Identity Federation, but another one can't.
The permissions settings in GCP don't specify an instance ID - I've restricted the permissions using roles, which both the AWS EC2 instances have got.

I get the following error:

```
GaxiosError: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>401 - Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 - Unauthorized</h1>
 </body>
</html>

    at Gaxios._request (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:141:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AwsClient.getAwsRegion (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsclient.js:196:26)
    at async AwsClient.retrieveSubjectToken (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/awsclient.js:102:27)
    at async AwsClient.refreshAccessTokenAsync (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js:283:30)
    at async AwsClient.getAccessToken (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js:160:13)
    at async AwsClient.getRequestHeaders (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js:177:37)
    at async AwsClient.getProjectId (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js:216:29)
    at async GoogleAuth.getExternalAccountClientProjectId (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:605:16)
    at async GoogleAuth.findAndCacheProjectId (/home/ubuntu/trader2/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:157:35)
```

Why can one instance call it, but another can't?

Answer (score 1):

The call that is failing is the instance trying to get its metadata (specifically the region it is in) using AWS's metadata service. Nothing to do with Google.

For this, it calls `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`.

Right click the instance, choose Instance Settings, Modify Instance Metadata Options:

[image: Modify Instance Metadata Options]

Ensure that the "IDMSv2" setting is set to 'Optional', *not* Required!

[image: IDMSv2 setting]

It can be tested by ensuring that

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
works (it should return the region, e.g. `us-east-1` in plain text, rather than 401 Unauthorized)

Comment: Thank you for both questions and their solutions.